# Spinor expectation value and measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, measurements

I have a question about the difference between expectation value and probability of measurement. 
consider the spinor $\zeta = [-3\ \ 4i\ ]^T$ . The expectation value of $S_x$ is zero because : $$\langle S_x\rangle\ = \zeta^\dagger S_X \zeta$$ Now if we measure $S_x$ the possible results will be $+ \frac{\hbar}{2} \;\&\; -\frac{\hbar}{2}$ can someone explain why the possible result is different with expectation value?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation value is a single number, it is the sum of all the possible values with a weight based on how often you get the result.

So $\langle S_x\rangle=P(+\frac \hbar 2)\frac{\hbar}{2}+P(-\frac \hbar 2)\frac{-\hbar}{2}$

And you can get the probabilities by projecting the original spinor onto the eigenspaces of the operator and comparing the $L^2$ squared norm of the projection and then you can deduce that $P(+\frac \hbar 2)\frac{\hbar}{2}+P(-\frac \hbar 2)\frac{-\hbar}{2}$ which by definition equals $\langle S_x\rangle$ numerically also equals $\zeta^\dagger S_x\zeta/\zeta^\dagger \zeta$ because of the probabilities.

Namely you can write the spinor as a combination of eigenvectors and then imagine the eigenvectors as wanting to hit the operator and then have the result hit the left spinor.  each eigenvector, when it hits the operator, gives you the eigenvalue and then when hitting the left spinor gives you the $L^2$ norm of that eigenvector because of the mutual orthogonality of the eigenvectors.

And since the ratio of the projection to the original is the probability you get all the terms in the sum.

Let's see the details. When you write your state as $\zeta=\alpha\zeta_++\beta\zeta_-$ then since $\zeta^\dagger_+\zeta_+$=$1$=$\zeta^\dagger_-\zeta_-$ and $\zeta^\dagger_+\zeta_-$=$0$=$\zeta^\dagger_-\zeta_+$ we get the projections are $\alpha\zeta_+$ and $\beta\zeta_-$ and so their $L^2$ squared norms are $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ respectively and the original squared norm before the projections  is $\zeta^\dagger\zeta$ so the probabilities are $|\alpha|^2/\zeta^\dagger\zeta$ and $|\beta|^2/\zeta^\dagger\zeta.$ Thus $$\begin{align}\langle S_x\rangle &= P(+\frac \hbar 2)\frac{\hbar}{2}+P(-\frac \hbar 2)\frac{-\hbar}{2}\\ &= \frac{|\alpha|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\frac{\hbar}{2}+\frac{|\beta|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\frac{-\hbar}{2}\\ &= \frac{|\alpha|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\frac{\hbar}{2}1+\frac{|\beta|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\frac{-\hbar}{2}1\\ &= \frac{|\alpha|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\frac{\hbar}{2}\zeta^\dagger_+\zeta_++\frac{|\beta|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\frac{-\hbar}{2}\zeta^\dagger_-\zeta_-\\ &= \frac{|\alpha|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\zeta^\dagger_+\frac{\hbar}{2}\zeta_++\frac{|\beta|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\zeta^\dagger_-\frac{-\hbar}{2}\zeta_-\\ &= \frac{|\alpha|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\zeta^\dagger_+S_x\zeta_++\frac{|\beta|^2}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\zeta^\dagger_-S_x\zeta_-\\ &= \frac{\overline \alpha \alpha}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\zeta^\dagger_+S_x\zeta_++\frac{\overline \beta \beta}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\zeta^\dagger_-S_x\zeta_-\\ &= \frac{\overline \alpha \alpha\zeta^\dagger_+S_x\zeta_++\overline \beta \beta\zeta^\dagger_-S_x\zeta_-}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\ &= \frac{ (\alpha\zeta_+)^\dagger S_x\alpha\zeta_++ (\beta\zeta_-)^\dagger S_x\beta\zeta_-}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\ &= \frac{ (\alpha\zeta_+)^\dagger S_x(\alpha\zeta_++\beta\zeta_-)}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\&+ \frac{(\beta\zeta_-)^\dagger S_x(\alpha\zeta_++\beta\zeta_-)}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\ &= \frac{ (\alpha\zeta_+)^\dagger S_x\zeta+ (\beta\zeta_-)^\dagger S_x\zeta}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\ &= \frac{ (\alpha\zeta_++\beta\zeta_-)^\dagger S_x\zeta}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\ &= \frac{\zeta^\dagger S_x\zeta}{\zeta^\dagger\zeta}\\&=\zeta^\dagger S_x\zeta/\zeta^\dagger\zeta.
\end{align}$$

Note we could add those vectors on the right because they were eigen to $S_x$ and because $\zeta^\dagger_+\zeta_-$=$0$=$\zeta^\dagger_-\zeta_+$ (which held because the operator has orthogonal eigenvectors). So the true definition is $\langle S_x\rangle=P(+\frac \hbar 2)\frac{\hbar}{2}+P(-\frac \hbar 2)\frac{-\hbar}{2}$ and we get $\langle S_x\rangle=\zeta^\dagger S_x\zeta/\zeta^\dagger\zeta$ because the operator $S_x$ is hermitian (making the eigenvectors orthogonal) and because of what the probabilities equal (they equal the ratio of the norm squared pre- and post- projection onto the eigenspaces).